# Mac osx laptop block keychain popups when forgotten password

Tags: macos, mac

I have pop ups asking for keychain access coming continually on my screen - I can now not get rid of them at all and my computer will no longer let me access facebook from iphoto to share photos adn I have an internet business - I tried following the advice adn went to keychain access adn tried to delete the keychains but I seem to have made things worse and now it will not let me change anything as it asks for the keychain password to delete or change the keychain - I have tried a thousand passwords but with no luck I just cannot remember a thing -

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a key-chain is to have one master password, such that all other passwords (the keys on a key chain) stored are secure. What is likely happened is that Mac OS X has stored all your website passwords in the keychain.

As per Apple's support page, the solution is to create a new key chain:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201609

If that does not work, the keychain might be managed by iCloud (https://www.apple.com/icloud/) which would likely require the assistance of Apple.